# HttpPostedFileBase always null in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

hello every body I have used bootstrap wizard in my project with html form and inside it I used MVC Html.BeginForm and i post data and works fine there is no any problem except when i add apart of multi up-loader I always get it null files but post the other data is OK when i remove html form tag it upload works but the wizard stopped this is my trial if there any suggestion ?

```
<div class="tabbable-line tabbable-full-width" id="form_wizard_1">


<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="submit_form" method="POST">


    <div class="tab-content">

        <div class="alert alert-danger display-none">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button> text
        </div>



        <div class="row profile-account">

            <div class="col-md-3">


                        <ul class="ver-inline-menu tabbable margin-bottom-10">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cog" style="padding:0px;"></i> upload
                                </a>
                                <span class="after"> </span>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                </div>
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "postdata", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                            {
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                @*@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">

                                            <div class="m-heading-1 border-green m-bordered">
                                                <h3>add files</h3>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="m-heading-1 border-after-green-steel m-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;">
                                        @for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                                        {
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.files, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control" })<br />

                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                    </div>

                </div>
</form>
    </div>

<div class="form-actions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn default button-previous">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> back
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-outline blue button-next">
                go on
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn blue button-submit">
                save
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have nested forms which is invalid and not supported (delete you outer `<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="submit_form" method="POST">` element). And you submit button is not even inside you form

Comment: i know  nested forms which is invalid and not supported (And you submit button is not even inside you form) i add it inside the form and it works with me and posted data except files upload always has null values which is my problem

Comment: Because your outer form (which is the one that is posted) does not have the `enctype` attribute. And if you know that is not valid then why are you doing it? And it will not work consistently across browsers!

Comment: even if i removed html form and add the button inside mvc BeginForm it always return files null

Comment: Well you have not shown your POST method signature, but it would need to contain a parameter for a model containing a `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files` property of just a `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` parameter

Comment: thanks for everyone it has been worked and i removed html form